# Express.js blogging application bug: filtering posts by category throws "Cast to ObjectId failed" failed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I have *Posts* that are grouped into *Categories*, each in its own collection.

I run into a problem trying to filter posts by category. To obtain the post by category url, I turn the category name into a slug and use it this way:

```
Posted in <a href="/<%= post.category.cat_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); %>"><%= post.category.cat_name %></a>
```

In the public routes file I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const postsController = require('../../controllers/front-end/posts');

// Express router
const router = express.Router();

// Get Posts
router.get('/', postsController.getPosts);

// Get Single Post
router.get('/:id', postsController.getSinglePost);

// Get Posts by Category
router.get('/:catname', postsController.getPostsByCategory);

module.exports = router;
```

The **Post** model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    full_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    post_image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

The **Category** model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cat_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

In the Posts controller I turn the slug back into category name to filter posts *by category name*:

```
exports.getPostsByCategory = (req, res, next) => {

    function titleize(slug) {
            var words = slug.split("-");
            return words.map(function(word) {
                //return word;
                return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            }).join(' ');
        }

    const postCategory = titleize(req.params.catname);

   const posts = Post.find({ cat_name: postCategory }, (err, posts) => {
        console.log('Category: ', postCategory);
        if(err){
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('default/index', {
                moment: moment,
                layout: 'default/layout',
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                page_heading: 'XPress News',
                page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                posts: posts.reverse(),
            });
        }
    }).populate('category');
};
```

The line `console.log('Category: ', postCategory)` outputs `Category:  Favicon.ico` *instead of the category name*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all - look at the moment where you ask DB - you need to await the answer, so you should use `Promise.than()` or `async/await` in your routes ...
Another one from request you get STRING as parameter - but in mongo schema you have Object...

So you should receive smth like `"CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed..."`,
it depends on your vision you can: first select category from `category.db =>` so you receive category Object after that you can search the posts using this object ..., or you can first populate results of posts by category (obtain plain category fields) and make further search...

Answer (score 2):

if I read this correctly, res is expect json pairs.

I am guessing your `post.reverse()` does not output in json format.

Comment: `post.reverse()` returns a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

`category` in your `post`-schema  is a `$ref` to the `category`-schema, which is why it holds an `objectId`. In order to reference and actually query your `category`-schema while using `.find()`, you need to populate it first:

```
Post.
  find({}).
  populate({
    path: 'category',
    match: { cat_name: postCategory}
  }).
  exec((err, posts) => {
    // ...
  });
```

The mongoose documentation for `$ref/populate()` is a bit hidden [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), in case you want know more about it.

Comment: I need a *list* of posts , not a single post. And they are posts *not* storyes.

Comment: Change it to find instead of findOne

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lilian Baxan, here is the right `getPostsByCategory` method in `controllers\front-end\posts.js`:

```
const Category = require('../../models/categories');
//more code here

exports.getPostsByCategory = async (req, res, next) => {

    function titleize(slug) {
        var words = slug.split("-");
        return words.map(function(word) {
            //return word;
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }).join(' ');
    }

    const postCategory = titleize(req.params.catname);

    const singleCategory = await Category.findOne({cat_name:postCategory})

    const posts = await Post.find({ category : singleCategory }, (err, posts) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            res.render('default/index', {
                moment: moment,
                layout: 'default/layout',
                website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
                page_heading: 'XPress News',
                page_subheading: 'A MEAN Stack Blogging Application',
                posts: posts.reverse(),
            });
        }
    }).populate('category');
};
```